# Amazon SQS missing method

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to create an instance of an AmazonSQS by using

```
AmazonSQS sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1).build()
```

but I get an error message stating that a method is missing.
It looks like `getAdvancedConfig()` can't be called.
Can anyone give help with creating this AmazonSQS?

Comment: please share the code you have tried with AWS SDK version.

Comment: Make sure your Java SDK version is up to date.

Comment: Much appreciated @jarmod,  was using the 633 version of aws-java-sdk-bom instead of 634. Another lesson learnt by an apprentice lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are correctly using the SDK documentation and are calling a valid method name on a class, then 'method missing' is almost always an indication that the SDK you are using is back-level.

The fix is to get the latest SDK.